# Android Equalizer custom presets aren't applying

Tags: android, audio-player, equalizer, android-music-player

Im trying to change the current presets but somehow Im failing.Im able to make a `spinner` with all the Preset names. But when I try to apply them only the first `seekbar` (60HZ) changes (also the sound doesnt sound like it applied the right preset)

```
equalizerPresetSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            m_equalizer.usePreset((short)position);
            short numberFrequencyBands = m_equalizer.getNumberOfBands();
            final short lowerEqualizerBandLevel = m_equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];

            for(short i=0;i<numberFrequencyBands;i++)
            {
                SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(i);
                seekbar.setProgress(m_equalizer.getBandLevel(i)-lowerEqualizerBandLevel);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And yes ... the IDs of `Seekbar` are 0,1,2 etc. because Im building them dynamic

Comment: no one got an idea ?